# How do I get datetime from date object python?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I get datetime from date object python?

I think of

```
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()
date_time = dt.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
```

Any easier solution?

Comment: Read here:http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks, I read it before asking the question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

```
mydatetime = datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)
```

or

```
mydatetime = datetime.combine(d, datetime.time())
```

or

```
mydatetime = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(d.toordinal())
```

I think the first is the most commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import datetime

print 'Now    :', datetime.datetime.now()
print 'Today  :', datetime.datetime.today()
print 'UTC Now:', datetime.datetime.utcnow()

d = datetime.datetime.now()
for attr in [ 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond']:
   print attr, ':', getattr(d, attr)
```

or

```
mdt = datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day) #generalized
```